# Javascript round up to the nearest integer

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an online store. i'm create calculate heavy goods for shipment, but i have a problem in heavy goods.

I want when total heavy goods example :

3.0  to  3

3.1  to  4

3.2  to  4

untill

3.9  to  4

i'm confused when heavy goods in (3.1 to 3.4) this result is 3 i want change this result to 4

**This is my code**  or [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/au51uj3r/4/)

```
var num = 3.4;
var n = num.toFixed()
alert(n);
```

Help me, Thank's

Comment: Are you looking for the [`Math.ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) method?

Comment: What should happen if the number is `3.05`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Math.ceil` function.

```js
var num1 = 3.0;
var num2 = 3.1;
var num3 = 3.9;

console.log(Math.ceil(num1));
console.log(Math.ceil(num2));
console.log(Math.ceil(num3));
```

Comment: "always round up to the nearest integer" sounds a bit contradictory to me

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for `Math.ceil`.

```
Math.ceil(3.0); // 3
Math.ceil(3.1); // 4
Math.ceil(3.8); // 4
```

Comment: Thank's, sorry previosly i don't know Math.ceil()

Comment: first != best..

Comment: Also, deleting comments is not the way to discuss on SO.

Comment: @xoxox totally agree +10

Answer (score 3):

you can use [Math.ceil()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_ceil.asp) function of JavaScript

```js
var num = 3.4;
var n = Math.ceil(num);
console.log(n);
```

Comment: Thank's, sorry previosly i don't know Math.ceil()